# gzuncompress has trouble with smart quotes

Tags: php, smart-quotes

My first question on Stack Overflow.

With a lot of my PHP code around it, gzuncompress is doing a reasonable job of decompressing code from a PDF file but it goes awry quite badly if it encounters "smart double quotes". In my case, it missed several words.

It loses "smart single quotes" completely but it correctly processes "straight single quotes" and "straight double quotes".

Has anyone fixed this problem in gzuncompress?

Comment: What about any code? Would be possible to show any code? Hard to help you if I don't see code that makes you problems.

Comment: `code      $UncompressedRecord = gzuncompress($PageStream, $LengthOfPageStream);`

Comment: Here is a fragment of the output file from gzuncompress that is causing the trouble.. I do a fairly straightforward post-process of this file with PHP to get the final text.

Comment: [(ch)-4(a)4(n)8(g)7(e)-12( )5(o)-4(f)5( )5(sc)7(en)6(e)-12( )16(wo)3(u)-4(l)7(d)11( )5(pr)6(o)-4(vi)-5(d)11(e)-12( )5(s)9(o)-4(m)16(e)-12( )5(m)16(en)-4(ta)3(l)-3( )16(sti)-6(m)5(u)6(l)-3(a)4(t)10(i)-3(o)6(n)-2(.)] TJ
ET
BT
1 0 0 1 361.42 306.41 Tm
[( )] TJ
ET
BT
/F4 11.04 Tf
1 0 0 1 92.664 286.97 Tm
[<002B>7<0048>-12<0003>5<005A00440056>10<0003>-5<0051>8<0052>-4<00570003>-6<0055>16<0048>-12<0044>15<004F>-3<004F>7<005C>-2<0003>-5<0044>4<0003>5<00B40046>-3<004C>7<0057005C>-3<0003>-5<0050>5<0044>4<0051>8<00B5000F0003>-2<004B>-2<